# Push data to an embedded array using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My Schema look like this

```
var Company ={
    Name 
    Email 
    Location 
    Industry 
    Creator 
    PostedJobs : [{
        JobName 
        JobType 
        JobLocation 
        JobSalary
        Applicants : [{
            Name 
            Status 
        }]
    }]
}
```

to push job here is my route code which is working

```
router.post('/:name' , isLoggedIn , function(req , res , next) {
    var JobName = req.body.JobName;
    var JobType = req.body.JobType;
    var JobLocation = req.body.JobLocation;
    var Salary = req.body.Salary;
    var postedJob = {JobName : JobName, JobType : JobType, JobLocation : JobLocation, JobSalary:Salary};
    var name = req.params.name;
    Company.findOne({Name : name}).then(function(Company) {
        Company.PostedJobs.push(postedJob);
        Company.save();
        req.flash('sucess_msg' , 'Job Added Sucessfully');
        res.render('dashboard',{
            "Company" : Company
        });
    });
});
```

now i want to push applicants on apply button 
apply code is

```
router.get('/:id/apply' , isLoggedIn , function(req , res , next) {
    var appicant = { Name : req.user.FirstName,
            Status : "Applied"
        };
        Company.find({'PostedJobs._id' : req.params.id}).then(function(job) {
        Company.PostedJobs.Applicants.push(applicant);
        Company.save();
        req.flash('sucess_msg' , 'Job Added Sucessfully');
        res.redirect('/jobs');
    });

 });
```

i also tried

which is not working and i wont know what to do with this

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? when pushing applicants.

```
Company.PostedJobs[0].Applicants.push(applicant);
```

Comment: Still that issue mate

Comment: the page does not post any thing its just stuck like slow browsing